# Can diff mode empty lines be utilized outside diff mode?

Tags: vimdiff

In diff mode, deleted lines are indicated by a colored block (green below). The `'number'` line numbers are skipped for this block.

Is it possible to emulate this behavior (screen-width colored blocks that act as separators) with Vim commands in a script, or is this only possible for diff mode from specific Vim internal C code written for this functionality, but not exposed through any Vimscript API?

[image]

Comment: Partial solution maybe, you can use `diffexpr` to manually set where the blocks go.